# How can we detect when a WCF client has disconnected?

Tags: wcf

Is there any way of finding out when a WCF client has disconnected. Currently the only approach seems to be to wait until a call on the client from the service eventually times out.

I have tried subscribing to the OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted event but unfortunately it is never called; my understanding was that this event should be fired when the client disappears. On the other hand, when things close down gracefully OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closed is called.

In our application we only support a single client connection at a time, hence when somebody closes and re-starts the client app it would be nice if the server could be made aware of the the disconnection, tidy up gracefully and then accept another connection.

Yes, clients will disconnect gracefully most of the time, but this can't be guaranteed. Currently the only option seems to be to poll the client and wait for a CommunicationTimeout, which is hardly ideal.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, a service need not have knowledge of client's state. But it can insist on whom to serve for by dictating the authentication needs, concurrency limitation etc.

If you intention is to make sure only one client is served at a time, you can simply opt for Single Concurrency mode.

For example.

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Single)] 
public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorConcurrency
```

This will ensure only one client request is served at a time. Following link may help you as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx

**EDIT**

If you think an user's action of keeping the channel open does disturb the other user's work, it may not be the usual case.

Because each user's call is considered to be a different session. By default WCF calls are considered to be instantiated per call.

If you would like to persist data between user's calls, you may opt for perSession instancing mode.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)] 
public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorInstance
```

This would make sure that each user would have an instance of the service which would not inturrupt servicing the other user.

You can set the concurrency mode accordingly i.e Multiple or Reentrant if you wish. Even if the concurrency mode is single, when a response is sent back to the user the service would be ready to serve the next user. It won't wait for the client to close the connection. User's connection would be useful only to keep the session live.

Comment: Yes, making sure that we only serve a single client at a time is no problem. The problem is where the single client app disappears ungracefully and is then brought back up - it can't connect because the server thinks that the previous instance is connected (until it finds out that this is not the case via a comms timeout).

Comment: Okay. Question: Are you sharing the same data across multiple users? In other words, if user A does some changes, user B would be able to see it? (Don't consider updating of data in Database or something, its a question in the service alone)

Comment: There's just a single client - no sharing of data. Ideally I'd like a better way of detecting when the client has disconnected. Does anyone have any idea of why the OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted event may not be firing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IChannelInitializer and hook up Channel Close and Channel faulted events to detect graceful or abrupt closing of the client. Refer to a very nice post on this by Carlos - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/14/wcf-extensibility-initializers-instance-context-channel-call-context.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use Callback Operations to make a call to the client to see if its still connected.

Take a look at this article on [MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx)

Comment: Currently I am making calls on the client and handling TimeoutExceptions when they occur. It's hardly ideal though. I'd love to know why the fault event isn't firing. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the cirmustances which would lead to it firing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected == false
{
...
}
```

it can help you

Comment: Is this really relevant in WCF?

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using a "disconnection detector" like this:

```
// Code based on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2012/02/13/wcf-extensibility-initializers-instance-context-channel-call-context/
public class WcfDisconnectionDetector : IEndpointBehavior, IChannelInitializer
{
    public event Action Disconnected;
    public int ConnectionCount { get; set; } = 0;

    public WcfDisconnectionDetector() { }
    public WcfDisconnectionDetector(Action onDisconnected) => Disconnected += onDisconnected;

    void IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime cr)
        => cr.ChannelInitializers.Add(this);
    void IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher ed)
        => ed.ChannelDispatcher.ChannelInitializers.Add(this);
    void IEndpointBehavior.Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }
    void IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) { }

    void IChannelInitializer.Initialize(IClientChannel channel)
    {
        ConnectionCount++;
        Trace.WriteLine($"Client {channel.SessionId} initialized");
        channel.Closed += OnDisconnect;
        channel.Faulted += OnDisconnect;
    }

    void OnDisconnect(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectionCount--;
        Disconnected?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Install it before calling `ServiceHost.Open`:

```
    var detector = new WcfDisconnectionDetector();
    serviceHost.Description.Endpoints.Single().EndpointBehaviors.Add(
      new WcfDisconnectionDetector(() => {/*disconnected*/}));
```